# D3.js display multiple information on map

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, plot, maps

I have to display on a map the weather information registered by weather stations in the world.I have position (the latitude and longitude) of the weather stations and all the data they collected.I have a form in which i insert temperature and windspeed. Then I search through all the files to find those values and when I find them I plot them on the map. Unfortunately if the same weather station registered the same type of teperature and windspeed in two different dates (i.e. 1991-1 and 1992-2) with my code I can show only the most recent date on the map because the gpoint attribute gets overwritten every time a new values is found.
I'd like to avoid this problem and display on the map all the dates in which a certain windspeed and temperature have been found.

```
function evaluate() {
    $('#result').empty();
    var temp = document.getElementById("temperature").value;// get parameters from temperature and windspeed field
    var wind = document.getElementById("windspeed").value;
    var count;

    for(var i=1991; i<1993;i++){// the variable i loops through year and has to start with starting year available
        for(var j=1; j<13;j++)  {//j goes through moths
            example = i+"-"+j+".json";  //loops through the available files
            $.ajax({
                url: example,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    var distance;
                    var array= data;
                    for(var z=0; z < array.length; z++){//search for closest station
                        distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(temp - array[z].temperature, 2) + Math.pow(wind - array[z].windspeed, 2));//euclidean distance
                        if(distance < 0.1){
                            var text= array[z].station+"\n in\n "+i+"-"+j;//creates the variable text to display on the map
                            var appendItem ='<ul>Info:\n in\n'+i+"-"+j+'<br><a>Station:'+array[z].station+'</a><br><a>Longitude:'+array[z].longitude+'</a><br><a>Latitude:'+array[z].latitude+'</a><br><a>Temperature:'+array[z].temperature+'</a><br><a>Windspeed:'+array[z].windspeed+'</a><br><a id="tit" class="btn-primary" href="http://www.google.com/maps/place/'+ array[z].latitude +','+ array[z].longitude+'"; target="_blank";>GoogleMaps</a></ul>';//call to googlemaps

                            $('#result').append(appendItem);
                            addpointo(array[z].longitude,array[z].latitude,text)//send points to funtipon that plots points on the map
                        }

                    }

                },
                async:false
            }); 
        }
    }   
}

function addpointo(lat,lon,text) {
    var gpoint = g.append("g").attr("class", "gpoint");
    var x = projection([lat,lon])[0];
    var y = projection([lat,lon])[1];

    gpoint.append("svg:circle")
        .attr("cx", x)
        .attr("cy", y)
        .attr("class","point")
        .style("fill","purple")
        .attr("r", 1.5);

    //conditional in case a point has no associated text
    if(text.length>0){
        gpoint.append("text")
            .attr("x", x+2)
            .attr("y", y+2)
            .attr("class","text")
            .text(text);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your `addpointo` function call missing a semi-colon or was it just a typo?

Comment: I don't see anything missing in function call. As i wrote right now I have only the most recent date on the map because when I pass the "text" to addpointo it overwrites the previous values...